# SAS multiple dataset and Coalesce function

Tags: sas, dataset, coalesce

Good day,

I have old data with different format and updating it with new. Idea is that variable `WantedName` had been written with underscore `Wanted_Name` whereas new data is without this. No big deal I though.

EDIT: `WantedName` and `Wanted_Name` are SAS dates.

Original data:

```
year Wanted_Name 
2013  1234       
2013  4321       
2013  3241
```

and from year 2015 forward:

```
year WantedName 
2015 5678     
2015 8765
....
```

I tried the logic:

```
%macro macro_env;
data _null_; 
    call symput ("curr_year", year(date()) ); 
run;

data long_data;
    set 
    %do year=2013 %to &curr_year.;
        data.history&year.
    %end;
    ;
    WantedName=COALESCE(WantedName, Wanted_Name);
run;
%mend macro_env;
```

Nope. Did not work. For some reason it took the first value of `Wanted_Name` and pasted that over the whole data range except for the new data:

```
year Wanted_Name WantedName
2013  1234        1234
2013  4321        1234
2013  3241        1234
....
2015  .           5678     
2015  .           8765
```

Now I managed to fix the issue by removing the `coalesce` function and adding a additional data statement:

```
data long_data;
    set 
    %do year=2013 %to &curr_year.;
        data.history&year.
    %end;
    ;
run;

data long_data;
    set long_data;
    WantedName=COALESCE(WantedName, Wanted_Name);
run;
```

Question: **What happens or why isn't the original macro_env working?**

I thought datasets in `set` were first loaded and then function applied. (Which is working in the latter data statement. Apparently not... Maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the pdv implicitly retains variables that have been "set", and `wantedName` is not being flushed from the pdv when the earlier datasets (pre 2015) are being loaded.

The compiler made a space for it (by reading all the datasets in the set statement) but the set command does not (initially) replace the value of `wantedName`.

So - when the first observation is read, `wantedname` is missing and the first value of `wanted_name` is applied.

```
WantedName=COALESCE(., 1234); /* obs 1 */
```

In the second iteration, the value of `wantedname` has been retained, and so is used for every subsequent iteration until a dataset is read in that contains `wantedname`.

```
WantedName=COALESCE(1234, 4321); /* obs 2 */
```

The second example uses a dataset from the beginning that has the `wantedname` variable.

Great question!

Answer (score 4):

As answer form @Allan Bowe explains the issue is that variables sourced for datasets are automatically retained.  So you could add code to clear them.

```
data long_data;
  set data.history20: ; 
  WantedName=COALESCE(WantedName, Wanted_Name);
  output;
  call missing(wantedname,wanted_name);
run;
```

Or make a NEW variable.

```
data long_data;
  set data.history20: ; 
  new_WantedName=COALESCE(WantedName, Wanted_Name);
  format new_WantedName date9. ;
  drop WantedName Wanted_Name ;
  rename new_WantedName = WantedName ;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way to do this is to handle it with `rename` in the set statement.

```
data long_data;
    set 
    %do year=2013 %to &curr_year.;

        data.history&year.
          %if &year lt 2015 %then %do;
           (rename=wanted_name=wantedname)
          %end;
    %end;
    ;
run;
```

Cheaper (rename is cheaper than `coalesce` function) and simpler.

Comment: true, this would be a better way to achieve the desired outcome.  Or to use `proc datasets` to permanently rename the old files.

Comment: True+1. The motivation for the question is mainly to learn something. I've never considered that `pdv` logic would be an issue. (Well, now it's obvious,  after the fact. )